# Mapping two entities to each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a library project, I have a database table called `Employees` that has several columns such as `ManagerId` and `EmployeeId`. I would like to map `ManagerId` against an `EmployeeId`.

So the idea is that if there is an employee called "Max" and a manager called "Bob", I would like Max to have Bobs Id to show that the manager of Max is Bob.

Hope I am clear... I try to find out how can I solve this problem.

EmployeeController:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Employees = new SelectList(db.Category, "Id", "Employees");
    return View();
}

// POST: Employees/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,Salary,IsCEO,IsManager,ManagerId")] Employees employees)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Checks if there is a ceo
            var ceo = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsCEO == employees.IsCEO);
            if (ceo == null)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employees);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                // Informing the user about the problem
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage3 = "There is already a CEO in the database! You cannot create a second one!";
            }
        }

        return View(employees);
}
```

Hope I am making my self clear, please let me know if I must edit the question in order to make it more clear.

Regards

[picture for Adrian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InxKx.png)

Comment: Why not just add a Foreign Key into the Employee Class that is an Int that is equal to the manager ID?

Comment: @MathewHD could you be more specific and give a code example please?

Comment: Why are you posting MVC controller logic in a question on EF and how to set up entities? You haven't even shown the actual entity you're discussing.

Comment: @JanAdam I added an answer that should help you into the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each `Employee` to have a Manager you would need to add a `Foreign Key` to the `Employee` Class.

**Employee Class:**

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Key] [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // For autoincrement
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; } // Manager ID Foreign Key
    [Required]

    // Add other Database Values here
}
```

If you want to add a new `Employee` now you would need to get the Manager first to insert it into the `Employee`.

You could for example get the Manager with it's name or something similar

**Getting Manager with Name:**

```cs
int mID = 0;
string mName = "Test";

using(ForumDbContext context = new ForumDbContext())
{
    foreach(Manager manager in context.Managers
        .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Managers WHERE Name = '" + mName + "'").ToList<Manager>())
    {
        mID = manager.M_ID;
    }
}
```

We can now use this `mID` that we just got to create a new Employee with the corresponding Manager being the person we just searched for.

**Creating new Employee:**

```cs
Employee empl = new Employee
{
    ManagerId = mID,
    // Add other Database Values here
};

using(var context = new ForumDbContext())
{
    context.Employees.Add(empl);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! Where should I put your code in "Getting Manager with Name" and Creating new Employee? I just dont know where excatly to put them

Comment: No problem you need to add it to the part where you are creating new employees, make sure to get the manager before creating a new employee.

Comment: So in the Create.csshtml? Or should that be in EmployeeController?

Comment: Hard to tell how do you create new employees?

Comment: I create it in Create.csshtml, but I am thinking that maybe I should add  your code to EmployeeController first? I am not sure

Comment: You need to make sure that the employeecontroller has the foreign key of manager  like shown above

Comment: After that you add the get manager with name code and below it create employee function, where you want to create a new employee (probably after taking some input from your website i guess?)

Comment: The Employee.cs model has the foreign key of the manager, I added that like you showed above. What I cannot understand is, where to put the "Getting Manager with Name" and "Creating new Employee".

Comment: You said you create new employees in the create.csshtml so somewhere there but without the code i can't tell you where exactly.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time! I don't know if it is possible or usual to ask for help by skype in this forum? I am just wondering if you would help me by Zoom or skype? Of course I understand if it is not possible and I respect that.

Comment: @JanAdam I sadly can't help you like that. I am at work right now. If it helped tough I would really appreciate if you mark my answer as the correct solution.

Comment: It did! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to reference the employees with forengkeys**

First of all:

1. Employees and Managers are both employees so you just need one DB-table
2. To reference a user to another user (Manager of employee) you need a table that holds the IDs
3. To do this the right way and have a nice performance you will need to reference the ID from the employe table (point 1) to the manager-foreignkey and to the employee-foreignkey (point 2)

If you never have heard about this maybe it sounds weird and incomprehensible. Here an example of the database and some test data. Let me know if you have any questions

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase;
CREATE DATABASE myDatabase character set UTF8mb4 collate utf8mb4_bin;
USE myDatabase;

create table `Employees`(
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(20) not null,
`surname` varchar(20) not null,       
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
last_modifed timestamp on UPDATE current_timestamp default current_timestamp
);

create table `EmployeeManager`(
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,    
FK_Manager int not null,
FK_Employee int not null,
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
last_modifed timestamp on UPDATE current_timestamp default current_timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE `EmployeeManager` ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_Manager) REFERENCES `Employees`(ID);
ALTER TABLE `EmployeeManager` ADD FOREIGN KEY (FK_Employee) REFERENCES `Employees`(ID);

INSERT INTO `Employees` (`name`, `surname`)  VALUES ('Max', 'Muller');
INSERT INTO `Employees` (`name`, `surname`)  VALUES ('Bob', 'Smith');

INSERT INTO `EmployeeManager` (`FK_Manager`, `FK_Employee`)  
VALUES (
    (SELECT ID FROM `Employees` WHERE `name` = 'Bob' AND `surname` = 'Smith'),
    (SELECT ID FROM `Employees` WHERE `name` = 'Max' AND `surname` = 'Muller'));
```

Comment: But I already have a database called LibraryDb and in that database I have a table called Employees. Why do I have to create a new employees table? Cant I solve this problem without redesigning the database?

Comment: You can use your database but in my opinion your database has the wrong structure... You can add a new table `EmployeeManager` to store the IDs or you could show me your database structure and I will try to figure something out

Comment: @JanAdam You don't need to create a new database. Just drop your `Employee` and your `Manager` table and add the tables from my answer (ignore the creation of the new database). I think this would be the best solution.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question and added a picture for you. Please see the picture above.

Comment: @AdrianEfford He is using Entity Framework so this answer doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @JanAdam I saw your picture... You need to reference the manager_id to a manager. I haven't seen the manager table in your picture... I recommend you to drop the manager_id filed and create the table `EmployeeManager` and the whole code below that line (see my answer). Of corse you will need to change the FOREGN KEY reference to your table name and fields

Comment: @AdrianEfford I see, it is soo much new and I dont know where to begin... Thanks for you answer!

Comment: @JanAdam I know... I had the same problem when I started with databases... Take a look at SQL ForeignKeys and SQL Joins... It seems to be complicated but they aren't. Good luck and happy coding :)